# Disable Spring Security for a selected port [with WebFlux Security]

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, spring-webflux

How can I disable security for a selected port? I need to give permanent access to for example 4200 port (Angular). I work with WebFlux Security.

```
@EnableWebFluxSecurity
@EnableReactiveMethodSecurity
public class SecurityConfig {

(...)
  int selectedPort = 4200;

  @Bean
  public SecurityWebFilterChain springSecurityFilterChain(final ServerHttpSecurity http) {
    return http
(...)
        .authorizeExchange()
        .pathMatchers("/menage").authenticated()
        .anyExchange().permitAll()
        .and()
        .build();
  }
```

In this example, I need to give permanent access (disable security?) for port 4200 to work with "/menage" path.

Of course this method won't work:

```
private RequestMatcher checkPort(final int port) {
    return (HttpServletRequest request) -> port == request.getLocalPort();
  }
```

Comment: dont serve your application on a different port, make an endpoint that will serve the index.html on the same port as the rest of your application.

Comment: This may help. whitelist local:4200 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59438237/spring-security-webflux-ip-whitelist